# SharePoint Add In - Use ratings and reviews

Tags: sharepoint, office-store

The Best practice guidelines suggest adding a request to rate and review our add-in and show an example that includes a 'Leave a Rating' button.
Unfortunately they do not provide an example of the link address.
Can anyone help with an example of how the address is constructed please?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question further? I am having some difficulties in understanding this

Comment: Link to best practices?

Comment: This document is part of the guidelines for SharePoint add-ins
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/create-effective-office-store-listings
I was querying how to add a link on first submit for a SharePoint hosted add-in and that has been answered thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to leave a review should be in the format 'https://store.office.com/writereview.aspx?assetid=WAxxxxxxxx' where `WAxxxxxxxx` is the WA ID generated once your add-in is approved to AppSource. This WA ID is not available until your add-in is approved. The WA ID is available from the URL of your add-in listing on AppSource.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.
So just to clarify, in order to add a link back to the review page I have to do it in an update to the app after it has been approved?

Comment: @AlanBell, Yes you can only generate the URL once the add-in is approved as the WA ID is not available until then. If the add-in is provider hosted, you can make this change in the backend without resubmitting. If the add-in is SharePoint hosted, you will need to submit the update for validation.